# Не видит сборку

Tags: c#, asp.net

Делаю по туториалу Троэлсена.

Создал веб приложение, добавил веб-форму. Далее добавил в проект сборку *AutoLotDAL*. В своем проекте добавил ссылку на него. В *web.config* не знаю что надо писать. Вставил как в туториале *connectionStrings* и ещё, пошерстив *stackoverflow*, добавил

```
<assemblies>
            <add assembly ...
```

Но это не помогло. В файле *Default.aspx* пишу

```
<%@ Import Namespace="AutoLotDAL" %>
```

Но ни один класс из него не видно.[image: 1][image: два]

Answer (score 1):

Это же ошибка студии, а не ASP.NET. При чем тут `web.config` и секция `<compilation>`?

У вас компилятор не находит зависимый проект потому что зависимый проект не смог собраться. А зависимый проект не смог собраться из-за слишком длинного пути (о чем вам русским по белому пишут во второй строчке на первом скриншоте). Перенесите все решение по-ближе к корню диска.